# Scala: issue with extractor objects, type inference

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

json4 [has](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/3.6/ast/src/main/scala/org/json4s/JsonAST.scala#L121) the following types:

```
sealed abstract class JValue
case class JString(s: String) extends JValue
//etc
```

I have the following json value:

```
    val json: JValue = JString("hi")
```

and I use it in a for-comprehension as such:

```
val token = for {
  JString(s) <- json
} yield s
```

Here is the question:

1. As it is, the token will be evaluated as `List("hi")` namely an instance of the type `List[String]`. My understanding was that it should instead be `Option[String]`. why `Option` -> `List`?
2. IntelliJ's type-"inference" helper, suggests setting the type `JValue` for the result of the for-comprehension. When you that however, you get a compile error. What's exactly at fault here? and why is the confusion happening?

Comment: I'm unable to compile your code as posted. The `<-` generator doesn't work for that type.

Comment: 1. Why do you think a `for` comprehension should return `Option`? It is pattern matching over `JString` and returns a `List` of the matches... 2. There is no way that `token` exactly like it is on your example to be of type `JValue`.

Comment: well IntelliJ is suggesting it'd be. so any idea why it might be confused?

Comment: @jwvh maybe try it by actually importing `json4s` types as opposed to defining them yourself?

Comment: [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why `List[String]`?

Well, as you can see [here](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/3.6/core/src/main/scala/org/json4s/MonadicJValue.scala#L279), that's what the json4s authors chose. They could have gone with `Vector[String]`, or `Array[String]`, but decided upon `List[String]`. I assume they had good reasons.

What's `withFilter()` got to do with it?

As we all learned on the first day of Scala class, `for` is not a control-flow language construct, but is actually syntactic sugar used to prettify nested `map`/`flatMap` constructs.

```
for {
  b <- a               // flatMap()
  if b.isSomeCondition // withFilter()
  c <- b               // map()
} yield c
```

It turns out that `withFilter()` is also employed when pattern matching in a `for` construct. So this...

```
for {
  JString(s) <- json
} yield s
```

...gets translated into this (roughly).

```
json.withFilter{
  case JString((s @ _)) => true
  case _ => false
}.map{
  case JString(s @ _) => s
}
```

The authors of json4s decided that `withFilter()` should return a `List` and thus that's the result of your `for` comprehension.

2. IntelliJ's confusion.

IntelliJ's syntax checker and suggestion engine is pretty good, but it's not perfect. Scala code can get rather complicated and it's not uncommon for IntelliJ to get confused. Trust the compiler. If it compiles without warning then just ignore the faulty type suggestions.